# Method of differences summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, partial-fractions

I was trying some Cambridge past papers and it said to first separate into partial fractions and then find the sum of the sequence, however after splitting inot partial fractions I'm not getting the terms to cancel out like I normally do with these questions. Is there something I'm missing
.been trying to manipulate the 3 sets of term but can't seem to get it . Thanks

$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac4{r(r+1)(r+2)}$$

Comment: What do you get after applying partial fractions?

Comment: (2/r) - 4/(r+1) + 2/r+2

Comment: Can you figure out $\sum a_r-a_{r+1}$? What about if $a_r=\frac2r-\frac2{r+1}$?

Comment: Yes I can do that since the terms cancel out easily

Comment: Then you've figured out the answer? :-)

Comment: I don't understand. How are those two things equal. Your sequence and the partial fraction one ?

Comment: With $a_r=\frac2r-\frac2{r+1}$, what does $a_r-a_{r+1}$ equal?

Comment: ahh I see what you did. How did you think of that ? Seemed a bit weird that text question would ask for partial fractions and then say hence but require me to do that

Comment: The only advice I can really give is practice, intuition, and that I've seen many similar problems before.

Comment: When performing partial fractions and telescoping, I would recommend trying to group terms of similar numerators and denominators though, which may require splitting something like $\frac4{r+1}$ into 2 or more separate fractions as was done here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take
$$b_{r}=\frac{1}{r(r+1)}.$$

Then

$$b_{r}-b_{r+1}=\frac{1}{r(r+1)}-\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{2}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{1}{2}a_{r}.$$

So
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{4}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=
2\sum_{r=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{r(r+1)}-\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)}\right)=
2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right).
$$

In fact, if you want to sum, via differences and telescopic summation,
any finite series with a general term of the form

$$\frac{1}{(r+k)(r+k+1)...(r+m-1)(r+m)}$$

where $k,m$ arew integers with $k<m$, then take

$$b_{r}=\frac{1}{(r+k)(r+k+1)...(r+m-1)(r+m-1)}$$

Comment: thanks alot I finally understand but is there any way of knowing what to let $a_n$ be ? Or how to bring these types of sequences into a form so that method of differences can apply ?

Comment: @user122343 Mostly, yes there is, depending on the general term of course. It is better to do exercises and enjoy discovering the choice that works for the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Using calculus of finite differences with rising factorials,

Let $S_n = \sum_{r=1}^n\frac4{r(r+1)(r+2)} = \sum_{r=1}^n4r^{-\underline3}$

Then by integrating, we get $S_n = 4\frac{r^{\underline-2}}{-2} + C$

$S_n = C - \frac{2}{(n+2)(n+1)}$

For $n = 1$, $S_n = 4/6 = C - 2/6 \implies C = 1$

So $S_n = 1 - \frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$